# How to run multiple websocket API calls concurrently?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

In the code below I'm making two calls to two different APIs. However, instead of running the calls one after the other I would like to run them concurrently. I understand there may be different ways of doing this and I was wondering if there is a prefered way?

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

omsg = {"op": "subscribe", "args": [{"channel": "instruments", "instType": "FUTURES"}]}

dmsg = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "public/get_index_price", "id": 1, "params": {"index_name": "btc_usd"}}

async def call_oapi(omsg):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://wspap.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/public?brokerId=9999') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(omsg)
        response1 = await websocket.recv()
        response2 = await websocket.recv()
        print(response1)
        print(response2)

async def call_dapi(dmsg):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(dmsg)
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)
        
def run(call_api, msg):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))

run(call_dapi, dmsg)
run(call_oapi, omsg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```py
def run(call_api, msg):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))

run(call_dapi, dmsg)
run(call_oapi, omsg)
```

Use

```py
async def main():
    await asyncio.create_task(call_dapi(json.dumps(dmsg)))
    await asyncio.create_task(call_oapi(json.dumps(omsg)))

asyncio.run(main())
```

You can do something similar with `asyncio.gather` but it is not the same. I think you want the above code.

- ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-an-asyncio-program
- ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task
- ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it throws an error: `loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop`

Comment: I think fixed the code.

Comment: The code isn't throwing any errors but it's not receiving anything from the api call and not getting any response. Basically nothing happens as it it wasn't awaiting the response.

Comment: Two `await` were missing, ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task

Comment: thx that works. there's also a set of closing brackets missing fyi.